# Spring Data JPA Configuration for Multiple Databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, datasource

How do I configure multiple databases with Spring Data JPA?

Just provide me some useful links so I can go through and configure multiple databases in sample Spring Data JPA Application.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest, this example, for multitenancy with springboot and data jpa:
https://github.com/wmeints/spring-multi-tenant-demo

Comment: Thanks I've forked this, will check.